Expectation of a Poisson random variable
Let $N_{\lambda}$ be a random variable having Poisson distribution with probability mass function given by
$$ P( N_{\lambda} = k) = \frac { \lambda^k e^{- \lambda} }{ k!}, $$ where $\lambda >0.$
Now, I want to calculate the expectation
$$ E \left[ N_{ax} + N_{ay} - 2 N_{a(x+y)/2}\right]^2,$$ where $a> 0$ and $0 \leq x < y.$
I got $ 2 a(x+y)$ in answer after expanding the expression. But the answer is given $ a(y-x).$ Can anyone help me in this?

There is no  $t $ in $ E \left[ N_{ax} + N_{ay} - 2 N_{a(x+y)/2}\right]$.

Sorry, there was a typo. Also, there is square on expectation.

Please show your work so that we can point out where your mistake is.

I expanded $(a+b-2c)^2$ expansion formula. Also, $E[ N_{ax}] = ax$ and
$E[N_{ax}]^2 = ax + a^2 x^2$.

All that is correct. You just have to check your algebra again.

After substitution, I get $ax+ a^2x^2+ ay+ a^2 y^2+ 2 a^2 xy+a(x+y)(2+ ax+ ay)- 2(a^2 x^2+ a^2 xy)- 2 (a^2 xy + a^2 y^2)$, which simplifies to $ 3a(x+y)$.

It appears that you missed one term in the expansion of $(a+b-2c)^{2}$.
